# ircII ansi escape sequences

Tags: console, irc, ansi

REHASH from my original question.

I'm trying to get VT100/ANSI escape codes working in an irc client (ircII).
What facilitates this, is the `screen.scr` file.

The apparent problem, is that I cannot get a working terminal working with the pseudo terminal.

`stty` yields this:

`stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

So, I believe if I solve this,and get a working terminal, I solve my initial problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Those look like VT100 escape sequences. What is your `$TERM` variable?

Comment: My ```$TERM``` variable is "linux"

Comment: [this page](https://modern.ircdocs.horse/formatting.html#ansi-escape-code-support) explains it reasonably well.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Sorry, but not well enough.. Are there any solutions?

Comment: looking at the source code -- probably not without substantial effort: *a large number of IRC clients today, even those using a terminal interface, do not support displaying text formatted using ANSI escape codes.* (this is one of those).

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: This question as it stands makes no sense. The title refers to ANSI escape sequences but the body talks about stty ioctls and some reference to an unstated problem. VTC as unclear

Comment: I edited my question. Hopefully it makes better sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Fool the client. Invoke it with `TERM=VT100 ircli ...`. This will set the value of `$TERM` for the duration of `ircli`'s execution only.

Comment: Thank you for that,  But, it isn't working. :(